# How do I merge OUTER JOIN and UNION results?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, full-outer-join

I have two tables, and I want ALL the data from both.
If the tables have a matching AssetID, then join them on one row. If not, then on separate rows.
A full outer join sounds like the right approach but I have a problem in how to select the keys depending on which table it comes from.

```
TABLE A                 TABLE B
AssetID | Valuable      AssetID | Protected 
-------------------    -------------------
123     | Yes           123     | Yes   
456     | No            321     | No
653     | Yes
```

*Goal:*

```
TABLE C     
AssetID | Valuable | Protected
---------------------------
123 | Yes   |Yes
456 | No    |
653 | Yes   |
321 |       |No


SELECT TableA.AssetID, TableA.Valuable, TableB.Protected
FROM (
    SELECT AssetID, Valuable
    FROM TableA
) ta    
FULL OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT AssetID, Protected
    FROM TableB   
) tb ON ta.AssetID=tb.AssetID
```

*Produces*

TABLE C

```
AssetID | Valuable | Protected
---------------------------
123     | Yes      |Yes
456     | No       |
653     | Yes      |
        |          |No              <<<< PROBLEM
---------------------------
```

and I'm missing the key

Comment: Note: your query as posted has syntax errors, you alias the tables to `ta` and `tb` but continue continue to use TableA & TableB.

Comment: Yep, all good ... it's pseudo code so I wasn't looking too closely.

Comment: But you want to make sure you have removed all errors first else people waste time looking into the wrong issue.

Comment: Yep, I agree, and thanks for the advice. Appreciate it. You guys are wizards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `coalesce` to take the non-null `assetID` from whatever table has it:

```
SELECT COALESCE(TableA.AssetID, TableB.AssetID) TableA.Valuable, TableB.Protected
FROM
(
SELECT 
    AssetID,
    Valuable
FROM 
    TableA
) ta

FULL OUTER JOIN 

(SELECT 
    AssetID,
    Protected
FROM 
    TableB

) tb

ON ta.AssetID=tb.AssetID
```

**Note:** You probably don't need the sub-queries, though, and omitting them can simplify the query considerably:

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(TableA.AssetID, TableB.AssetID) TableA.Valuable, TableB.Protected
FROM TableA
FULL OUTER JOIN TableB
ON TableA.AssetID=TableB.AssetID
```

Comment: OK, that's a great solution. What if there is a second criteria, like a LocationID? s it possible to coalesce on both AssetID and LocationID ?

Comment: @Maxcot you can use coalesce on any column you like...

Comment: @Maxcot `coalesce` takes a list of arguments and returns the first not-null one. They don't have to be from the columns you joined on, or even columns at all. You could even do something like `coalesce(tablea.assetid, tableb.locationid, 123)`

Answer (score 1):

To deal with Null Values we use Coalesce function. Alternatively in place of full join we can use left join followed by right join.

```
SELECT COALESCE(TABLEA.AssetID,TABLEB.AssetId) AS 
AssetId,TABLEA.Valuable,TABLEB.Protected
FROM TABLEA 
LEFT JOIN 
TABLEB ON TABLEA.AssetID = TABLEB.AssetID
UNION
SELECT COALESCE(TABLEA.AssetID,T1.AssetID) AS 
AssetID,TABLEA.Valuable,T1.Protected FROM TABLEA
RIGHT JOIN 
TABLEB T1 ON TABLEA.AssetID=T1.AssetID
```